# Xamarin.Forms - Как удалить элемент из ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin

В общем есть часть кода, которая использует ListView. Надо каким-то образом удалить элемент из ListView так, чтобы сразу строка удалилась. Удаление элемента из `List<MyClass>` (на который опирается ListView) делает это только после поворота экрана. Как это сделать сразу кодом?

Comment: Вместо `List<MyClass>` используйте `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`

Comment: @Bulson, Спасибо, уже сам дошел до этого)))